# Turbolinks Classic - leak of variables when called from inside Facebook Video API embed event and navigating across pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I am using Turbolinks Classic and have really weird phenomenon and my app is using Facebook SDK. Bascially, I load a facebook embed video and thank top [Facebook api events](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player/api), I hide some waiting spinners +actually show the video when I receive the information that Fb has started playing the video.

I am running into an issue I know the cause but can't find a solution, a clean solution to be precise. It is 100% related to Turbolinks as removing Turbolinks removes my issue.

Generally speaking, very early, I had, as many people on SO, a lot of issues with the SDK and Turbolinks so I used the solution used by many: http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/facebook.html

I have many deals and each has a profile page (html below). You can move form one deal to another by clicking a link inside deal.html

**Deal page html**

```
<div id="js-videosContainer" class="displayNone">
      <div  id = "js-fbVideoPlayer"
            class="fb-video"
            style="position: absolute;"
            data-href=""
            data-allowfullscreen="false"
            data-autoplay="true"
            data-show-captions="false"
            data-show-text="false"
            data-controls = "false">
      </div>      
  </div>  

<!-- spinners -->
<div id="fullPageLoadingSpinner" class="displayNone">      
    <span id="fullPageSpinnerText" class="displayNone">Loading video...</span>
    <span id="fullPageSpinnerText2" class="displayNone">Slow Connection, hang on...</span>
  </div>

<!-- link to next Deal's page -->
 <div class="col-xs-4 action-next">
            link_to @nextdeal    
          </div>
```

**Javascript file**

```
    // Variables
     var spinner                               = document.getElementById("fullPageLoadingSpinner");
      var textWithSpinner                       = document.getElementById("fullPageSpinnerText");
      var textWithSpinner2                      = document.getElementById("fullPageSpinnerText2");
      var $videosContainer                      = $('#js-videosContainer');

//make waiting spinners invisible
function spinnersInvisible() {    
    spinner.classList.add("displayNone");
    textWithSpinner.classList.add("displayNone");
    textWithSpinner2.classList.add("displayNone");
  }

//inspired by reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/facebook.html
loadAndInitializeFbSdk();
   if (!window.fbEventsBound) {
      bindFacebookEvents();
   }
}


function loadAndInitializeFbSdk() {

 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId             : fbAppId,
        autoLogAppEvents  : true,
        status            : false,
        xfbml             : true,
        version           : 'v2.12'
      });
      console.log("FB LIBRARY - FB Object initiated");

      var handleFbVideoResponse = function(msg) {

        if (msg.type === 'video') {
          my_video_player = msg.instance;

          //resetting certain variables required inside 
          //the var fbEventHandler = my_video_player.subscribe('event'...
          var $videosContainer    = $('#js-videosContainer');
          var $muteVideoBtn       = $('#st-mute-audio-control');
          var $unMuteVideoBtn     = $('#st-unmute-audio-control');

          playVideo();

          function playVideo() {           

            my_video_player.play();           
          }
          var fbEventHandler = my_video_player.subscribe('startedPlaying', function(e) {                 
            spinnersInvisible();//remove the spinners            
            $videosContainer.removeClass('displayNone');//show the video
            }
          });
   };
    (function(d, s, id){
      console.log('LIBRARY - Loading and initializing Facebook javascript SDK');
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id; js.async = true;
      js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
     }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')
    );
}

//inspired by reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/facebook.html
  function bindFacebookEvents() {
    $(document).on('page:fetch', saveFacebookRoot).
                on('page:change', restoreFacebookRoot).
                on('page:load', function() {
      if (typeof FB !== "undefined" && FB !== null) {
        // Instance of FacebookSDK
        FB.XFBML.parse( document.getElementById('js-videosContainer') );
      }
    });
    this.fbEventsBound = true;
  }
  function saveFacebookRoot() {
    if ($('#fb-root').length) {
      this.fbRoot = $('#fb-root').detach();
    }
  }
  function restoreFacebookRoot() {
    if (this.fbRoot != null) {
      if ($('#fb-root').length) {
        $('#fb-root').replaceWith(this.fbRoot);
      } else {
        $('body').append(this.fbRoot);
      }
    }
  }
```

There is NO issue at all when i just load deal1 page, or if I load deal2 page (separately). All is working great.
The issue arise when I load deal 1 page, then I click on the link_to @nextdeal to arrive on deal2 page: all the things that should be triggered inside my_video_player.subscribe('startedPlaying') (see above) actually don't trigger:

- the spinners don't hide when the video starts
- the video is not displayed.

After hours of analyzing, I discovered the reason or at least I know how to make this work but in a very dirty and not "Rails-"y way that can't be the right solution.

I found out that there must be an issue with the access to my variables declared when **using FB SDK and turbolinks**.

Indeed i can make the scenario work just by repeating all the variables INSIDE the FB SDK block

**- Issue1: the spinners don't hide when the video starts**

Here if I REPEAT all the variables I declared on top of the js file, and kind of write them down TWICE, directly inside the spinnersInvisible(), which is itself inside the FB event 'startedplaying', it works: the spinners now disappear when the video starts playing.

function spinnersInvisible() { 
    var spinner                               = document.getElementById("fullPageLoadingSpinner");
      var textWithSpinner                       = document.getElementById("fullPageSpinnerText");
      var textWithSpinner2                      = document.getElementById("fullPageSpinnerText2");
      var $videosContainer                      = $('#js-videosContainer');
    spinner.classList.add("displayNone");
    textWithSpinner.classList.add("displayNone");
    textWithSpinner2.classList.add("displayNone");
  }

**- Issue 2:  the video is not displayed.**

Here again I just need to include the variables more diretcly/closely inside all this Facebook fbAsyncinit block: I can put it diretcly inside the my_video_player.subscribe('startedPlaying' block just next to where i call $videoscontainer, but I tried to put it as high level (inside Facebook fbAsyncinit) and the video shows up now if I do this.

```
var handleFbVideoResponse = function(msg) {

        if (msg.type === 'video') {
          my_video_player = msg.instance;

          //redeclaring certain variables required inside FB block
          var $videosContainer    = $('#js-videosContainer');

}
```

So I made it work...but it's really annoying: **it means variables used in a function** (ex: spinnersInvisible() **or any variable directly** ($videoscontainer) used inside var fbEventHandler = my_video_player.subscribe('startedPlaying', function(e) {, **must be REPEATED**. Indeed they're already declared outside at the top of the js file and I need them to be accessed by other functions so I can't just remove it from the top level: I need to write them twice. It feels wrong but is the only way to make this work so far.

The solution often used to use $(document).on('page:change', function(){} did not work, at least by itself. I did try to put the variables and the function side a $(document).on('page:change', function(){}. I've copied the WHOLE js file inside $(document).on('page:change', function(){}  and it's does not change anything, that is to say, the spinners don't hide and the video does not show up when the video starts playing on page 2 when you come from page1.

**A crucial clue**

I was thinking it's like my app has a "leak" from page 1 to page 2. So I added a small piece of information inside the view , the deal of the present/current Deal.
On Deal 1, I sould find the id of deal1 and on page 2, the id of Deal 2.

```
<div id="js-videosContainer" class="displayNone" id="@deal.id"><!-- added here a data info -->
    <% if @has_video %>
      <div  id = "js-fbVideoPlayer"
            class="fb-video"
            style="position: absolute;"
            data-href=""
            data-allowfullscreen="false"
            data-autoplay="true"
            data-show-captions="false"
            data-show-text="false"
            data-controls = "false">
      </div>
  </div>
```

And I added a console.log to see what my app was actually using for the "spinner" variable. and I think it's a huge clue to what's happening.

```
  function spinnersInvisible() {
    console.log (spinner ) //added our beacon here
    spinner.classList.add("displayNone");
    textWithSpinner.classList.add("displayNone");
    textWithSpinner2.classList.add("displayNone");
  }
```

Note: In my app, page 1 has an id of 341 and page 2 an id of 353.

On page 1, my console outputs something correct:

```
 <div id="fullPageLoadingSpinner" data=341 >    
    <span id="fullPageSpinnerText" class="displayNone">Loading video...</span>
    <span id="fullPageSpinnerText2" class="displayNone">Slow Connection, hang on...</span>       
  </div>
```

then if i click on page1 @nextDeal link to arrive on Page2, I see this in the console:

```
 <div id="fullPageLoadingSpinner" data=341 >    
    <span id="fullPageSpinnerText" class="displayNone">Loading video...</span>
    <span id="fullPageSpinnerText2" class="displayNone">Slow Connection, hang on...</span>
  </div>
```

It should be `id=353` !!! but the app is still keeping "somewhere in memory" (i don't know the right word but that's how I can bets describe it)  that the var spinner is still the one of deal1! I think that'(s the issue and that's why copying TWICE/resetting each time inside FB the variables make it work/solve the issue.

The very very interesting thing is that if I call spinnersInvisible() outside all this Facebook block/var fbEventHandler = my_video_player.subscribe('startedPlaying)..., then the console.log displays the right information, first id=341 on Deal1,and then id=353 on deal2. So the issue is really when I call them INSIDE  the facebook block  var fbEventHandler = my_video_player.subscribe('startedPlaying', function(e) { .

This is a confirmation for me: it's like inside Fb SDK event 'startedplaying', the app thinks that var spinner is still the one of the previous page. I need to finda way to cleanly "reset"/refresh /tell the app to get the latest var spinner. My technique or doubling/putting twice everywhere the variables seems not the proper way, there must be another way...

I'm lost on how to solve this in a clean way !

Comment: where is facebook js api loaded?

Comment: The sdk is loaded on the js file. It's the block beginning with "function(d, s, id){       console.log('LIBRARY - Loading and"

Answer (score 2):

Try like this, `document.addEventListener "turbolinks:load"` will load on every pages.

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {

   //if button being created dynamically and static both works
   $(document).on("click", "#button",function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      spinnersInvisible();
   })

   //if button is static
   $("#button").on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      spinnersInvisible();
   });
})

function spinnersInvisible() {
    spinner.style.display           = 'none';
    textWithSpinner.style.display   = 'none';
    textWithSpinner2.style.display  = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. no still not working. same situation. Note: I used $(document).on('page:change', function(){ instead of document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() { as i am using Turoblinks Classic (see the compatibility equivalents https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/blob/master/src/turbolinks/compatibility.coffee)

Comment: @Mathieu im really lost, how do u load this file, is snipper button clickable or default spin on load ?

Comment: Many thanks for your help. the code on my js file is like 1000 lines so I had so simplify/sum up.  On load the spinners is not visible then the user clicks on a button to load the video. When i receive form facebook SDK's API the info that the video started playing, I remove spinners and show the video container.

Comment: i just edited completely my question because last night, I found that actually it's not only about turbolinks so the usual solution of page:change does not work. it's due to the combination of turbolinks and Facebook SDK.